# Timber | TWIG making array shift and add to end

Tags: wordpress, twig, wordpress-theming, timber

I am using Wordpress Timber which uses TWIG as the Templating Enginge. I am trying to get my array shifted, so i can then loop over it with TWIG.

```
array('Anna','Ben','Caroline','Emma','Daniel')
```

Which should end up as this:

```
array('Ben','Caroline','Emma','Daniel', 'Anna')
```

Is there a way with Timber to do this, or must I do it via PHP?

Comment: just do it with php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply solving it with PHP as DarkBee suggested.